# Referencing Horizontal Java Packages

Tags: java, package

I'm not sure why I can't process this right now, but I have four packages in one source folder:

```
./src/common
./src/server
./src/client
./src/unittest
```

Common uses no files from any of the others, but server and client use files from the common package. In each of the files in those packages I have `import common.*`. But when I run the compiler with `javac ./src/server/*.java` it can't find the `common` package.

The only info I can seem to find is for tree structured package hierarchies, but how do I reference something at the same folder height as me? Do I need to nest common inside both server and client? That seems likely to generate a lot of redundant code.

I'm sure this is probably a question someone has asked before, so I apologize, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to find those files *automatically* without having to specify them, you'll need to be in the package root, so run this *from within `src`*:

```
javac server/*.java
```

That would then work.

However, personally I would always specify *all* the code you want to build, rather than letting `javac` pick up extra bits. If you want to build the `common` code first, I'd do so and then add a classpath entry so that `javac` will pick up the compiled classes rather than the source code.

(Alternatively, I'd spend most of the time in an IDE where it's largely automatic, and then use a fuller build system such as Ant to do the actual building.)

Comment: I tried this sequence order too and got nothing:

`javac ./src/common/*.java`
`javac -classpath ./src/common ./src/server/*.java`

Comment: @SeaNick: No, you'd need `javac -classpath src ./src/server/*.java`. You always specify a package *root* directory as a classpath entry. The compiler will then look for a directory called `common` *within* that for classes in the `common` package.

Comment: Aha! Thanks! My brain no work good on Sundays... :-) Thanks a million!